# Adding baner photo to links

Tags: html, hyperlink, photo

I am looking for a way to add "baner photo" when pasting link in facebook/google/etc.

Sometimes when you're posting a link to website, there is photo banner under/above link and I am looking for that.

Comment: This topic is covered all over the internet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to achieve that, you need to know about **OG IMAGE**

we need to provide **OG IMAGE**, **OG TITLE**, and **OG DESCRIPTION** in head

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />


for twitter need to mention some other details


<meta property="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta property="twitter:description" content="" />
<meta property="twitter:image" content="" />
<meta property="twitter:card" content="" />
```

***Note:***  Whatever you enter in "title", it will display as TITLE text for the shared card, as well as description also

you need to pass your image link in the URL place